# How to disable or enable html component through JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" onkeydown="myHandler()"/>
    <select id="select">
        <option value = "a">a</option>
        <option value = "b">b</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    function myHandler() {
        if(document.getElementById("name")){
            document.getElementById("select").disabled = true;
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById("select").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```

Well, this is all I have done. This disables the select whenever I input something in input but the select will stay disabled even if erase all the inputs in the input box. What can I do to make the select selectable if the input field is empty?

Comment: what will be the initial state of `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `onkeyup` event to check the input value of the text box because the `onkeydown` event fire up after key down so while there is a single character in the text box it needs to clear one more time to check for the empty value condition.

The demo with your code is:

```js
function myHandler() {
 console.log(document.getElementById("name").value.trim());
 if (document.getElementById("name").value.length == 0) {
  document.getElementById("select").disabled = false;
  return;
 } else {
  document.getElementById("select").disabled = true;
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="myHandler()"/>
    <select id="select">
        <option value = "a">a</option>
        <option value = "b">b</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content to disabled it:

```
  function myHandler() {
    var input = document.getElementById("name");
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    if(input && input.value){
      select.disabled = true;
    } else {
      select.disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

See that code in Codepen: https://codepen.io/rodrigo73/pen/PdgewR?editors=1000

Comment: please use onchange="myHandler()". onkeydown there isn't yet any `input.value` and won't disable the select.

Comment: `onchange` is triggered only on focus lost. Maybe the `oninput` event can improve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason `document.getElementById("name")` will be `null` when you empty the `input`. You have to check the value of the input as well.

```
if(document.getElementById("name") && document.getElementById("name").value){
    document.getElementById("select").disabled = true;
    return;
}

document.getElementById("select").disabled = false;
```